How do I detect if media3 item transition has been triggered from next or previous seek?
I have implemented media3 with MediaSessionService or my song player service and I am using MediaController for my UI side. In my service I also have implemented MediaSession.Callback().
val mediaItems = streamerVm.getSongList().map { song ->
                    MediaItem.Builder().setMediaId(song.audio).setMediaMetadata(
                        MediaMetadata.Builder().setFolderType(MediaMetadata.FOLDER_TYPE_ALBUMS)
                            .setArtworkUri(Uri.parse(song.bannerSquare?.md))
                            .setArtist(streamerVm.getSeriesName()).setTitle(song.name)
                            .setExtras(putMediaItemsData()).build()
                    ).build()
                }
                controller.setMediaItems(
                    mediaItems,
                    getCurrentSongPosition(),
                    streamerVm.getCurrentPlayingSongProgressDataInMs()
                )

I am setting MediaItems using controller and these media items are being received correctly inside onAddMediaItems().
Now I am two buttons in my UI that calls contoller.seekToNext() and controller.seekToPrevious() respectively. When any of these two are clicked onMediaItemTransition(mediaItem: MediaItem?, reason: Int) is triggered.
Inside onMediaItemTransition(), I am getting the reason as Player.MEDIA_ITEM_TRANSITION_REASON_SEEK , which only tells me that the media item transition is due to seek.
Is it possible to know whether the media item transition seek is from next or previous seek?

Maybe try ForwardingPlayer: https://developer.android.com/media/media3/session/control-playback and https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/media3/common/ForwardingPlayer?hl=en Example:

Sorry, here ist the Example. At-Char dont work, replace (at) with At-Char: ForwardingPlayer forwardingPlayer = new ForwardingPlayer(exoPlayer) { (at)Override public void seekToNext() { super.seekToNext(); } (at)Override public void seekToPrevious() { super.seekToPrevious(); } };
